# Will linux operating system read a disc that requires another operating system?

Tags: software-installation

I have a PC DVD/ROM with a game on it that I want to install on my linux operating system computer.

When I insert the disc it says DVD was mounted automatically and some files pop up.

When I inserted the disk on another computer (using Windows) is asked me if i want to install the game.

On linux it dose not let me install the game.

Comment: That's because Windows software doesn't run on Linux natively. You could try using Wine (http://www.winehq.org/) to run it (Install PlayOnLinux from software center)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Due to reasons beyond my knowledge, most games that say "PC" mean "Windows Only". Unfortunately, this leaves Linux unable to do much. You might want to try [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) and run the install program on the disk, but it doesn't work as often as any of us would like.